# Google App Engine copying sender

Tags: google-app-engine, email

I am using the EmailMessage object in Python to send an email using the email service of Google App Engine.  I am using an admin account/email from my Google Apps domain.

The problem is that when I send an email via the service, the sender is apparently automatically blind copied.  There is not information about this in the headers nor anywhere else in the message sent to the recipent or the sender.

Does anyone know how this can be turned off?

(The google docs suggest that is an email is undeliverable then the bounce will go to the sender, which makes sense, but there is no problem with delivery.)

Comment: +1 - I see this behaviour too, sometimes. A while ago I found this thread: http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/e277b3639c1dd5d5/ but the behaviour I see doesn't seem to match what is described there, and neither what I see or that thread match what is described in the referenced documentation at http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/overview.html.

Answer (score 3):

It can't be turned off. The intent is to let users know when applications send mail on their behalf.